# Lower the privilege of an open process

Tags: c#, .net

Was wondering how i'd go about lowering a processes privileges ? I've seen how to elevate my own process using tokens but not how to lower some other process (not one that I started myself) lets say notepad for example.

thanks

Comment: Lowering a processes's privileges to do...what exactly?  Read data?  Write it?  What behavior do you want to restrict?

Comment: @YYY end the process, I'm making an anti-malware program (just basic) a common protection is that they make their privileges higher and then spawn threads to keep their process alive. I can kill the threads but only if I can lower their processes privileges

Comment: By making their privileges higher, you mean they elevate to Administrator, yes?  I'm just trying to understand, sorry.

Comment: @YYY basically the question is how to lower the processes privileges so that my process can kill it.